# How to use github api from postman

Tags: rest, api, github, postman, github-api

i want to create a file on my github account using github api through postman.

github api to create a file on github account:

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

can anyone tel me how to use this api in postman.

i have my public github account : https://github.com/ritzygithub/myfirstRepo

and in postman header i set

```
Authorization type to OAuth 2
Authorization : token <token>
PUT request with url: https://api.github.com/repos/ritzygithub/myfirstRepo/
```

[image]

Can you please help me out in this

Answer (score 4):

i just figured it out.. posting my answer here so that if anyone is facing same issue then this can help them.

In postman, set as PUT request with below URL

```
https://api.github.com/repos/YourUsername/YourRepo/contents/file.txt
```

Add Body:

```
{
  "message": "my commit message",
  "committer": {
    "name": "My name",
    "email": "my email"
  },
  "content": "base64encoded"
}
```

Header: 
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : token

Refer below Screenshot: 
[image]

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Just to add that GitHub has deprecated the credentials based authentication and now you will need to generate a token, by going into your account and accessing the developer settings.